replacing kube-master host - new host 'forbidden'
Im trying to update all the centos7 hosts in the fleet. Among these are a slew of kubernetes nodes + one master.
Ive built a new master node on Rocky9 and am trying to sub it in for the existing master.
Ive copied all the /etc/k8/pki files and did a backup/restore of etcd from old->new.
New host has same name and IP as previous.
Start containerd and then  kubeadm init --ignore-preflight-errors=DirAvailable--var-lib-etcd
I see these msgs:
kubelet_node_status.go:73] "Attempting to register node" node="kube-master.work"
eviction_manager.go:282] "Eviction manager: failed to get summary stats" err="failed to get node info: node \"kube-master.work\" not found"
controller.go:145] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="leases.coordination.k8s.io \"kube-master.work\" is forbidden: User \"system:node:kube-master\" cannot get resource \"leases\" in API group \"coordination.k8s.io\" in the namespace \"kube-node-lease\": can only access node lease with the same name as the requesting node" interval="7s"
kubelet_node_status.go:96] "Unable to register node with API server" err="nodes \"kube-master.work\" is forbidden: node \"kube-master\" is not allowed to modify node \"kube-master.work\"" node="kube-master.work"
server.go:304] "Unable to authenticate the request due to an error" err="[invalid bearer token, serviceaccounts \"metrics-server\" not found]"

So Ive missed copying some files or have missed a step in the (re)start. Suggestions on where I went awry?
-- EDIT
Looks like the new/old hostnames didn't quite align. I fixed this and tried the kubeadm init again. This time it succeeded and kubelet started up ok.. except that none of the namespaces from the original install were there.
-- MORE
Did another restore of etcd - making sure to update ownership and such. I can see namespaces now. Only remaining issue are these errors:
kubelet.go:2919] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized"
server.go:304] "Unable to authenticate the request due to an error" err="[invalid bearer token, service account token is not valid yet]"

-- FINAL
Looks like

weave is out of business
weave:latest has a missing file so it won't start

I ended up rolling back to weave 2.6.x.
